# Perforce changelists on website

Tags: php, mysql, perforce

Is it possible to get perforce changelist details on a remote web server?

I currently keep track of schedules and internal communication on a website, so I was wondering if I could integrate changelists.

Comment: Are you looking for P4Web? http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-web-client

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [P4PHP](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/04_php.html) to accomplish this.